# UTF-16 conversion given wrong hex value

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16, utf

Code snippet is :

```
String str = "h";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    String byteAsHex = Integer.toHexString(bytes[i]);
    buf.append(byteAsHex);
}
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Output is : `068` where LATIN SMALL LETTER H is 0068.

could you please tell me why leading 0 is missing?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-: "This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in hexadecimal (base 16) **with no extra leading 0s.**" (emphasis mine).  **If the unsigned magnitude is zero, it is represented by a single zero character '0'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `Integer.toHexString()` will always return the shortest possible representation of a number, that is, without any leading zeros.  So, in your case, you have an array of 2 bytes: `[0, 0x68]` and `Integer.toHexString()` is invoked twice, the first time it returns `0`, and the second time it returns `68`.

In order to solve this problem you are going to need to prepend `'0'` to each string returned by `Integer.toHexString()` if the string length is 1.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `Integer.toHexString(0)` results in `"0"`, but not `"00"`.

You can fix this issue when you replace

```
Integer.toHexString(bytes[i])
```

by

```
String.format("%02x", bytes[i])
```